# Delete files older than 30 and save 1

Tags: powershell

I need to have a clean-up script that remove all files older than 30 days but if file is older than 30 days it should save the last one. Possible? :)

I have tried a couple of parameters but cannot really get it to work.. guess I need a if/else clause?
Would appreciate any guide and help with this, thanks

```
$Daysback = "-30"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
$path = "C:\Data\*"

$save1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object {($_.Name -like "Test*.zip")} | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 

Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse    
{($_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays($Daysback))}
{
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
elseif ($save1)
{   
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
}
```

Comment: Have you missed some code out when you copied it here? Your code is incomplete and won't run at all in its current form...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
$Daysback = "-30"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
$path = "C:\Data\*"

$Items=Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.Name -like "Test*.zip") -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le ($DatetoDelete))}| Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
$Items|Select-Object -Skip 1 |Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $_.fullname
```

Get-ChildItem -> Filter, only get the items that name starts with Test and ends with .Zip that were written over 30 days ago. Sort them.

In the delete line, we use -Skip 1 to skip over the first item in the sorted list and remove the items by using their path.

Comment: What if it is having folders ? Are you checking the directories too ?

Comment: that script deletes all files except last one, in the folder I have a couple of files that are newer than 30 days and those need to be saved as well, it's only if file is older than 30 days I need to save last one.

Comment: Ahh I think I messed up the comparison operator -GE should probably be -LE since we want older files

Comment: `Remove-Item` takes pipeline input.  No need to slow it down with `%`

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified.  The below block will grab all files in `C:\Data` that meet the filter (faster than `Where-Object` significantly), then further reduces those based on their `CreationTime`, skips 1, and deletes the rest.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Data' -Filter 'Test*.zip' -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
                   $_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } |
    Sort-Object -Property 'LastWriteTime' -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Comment: @ps_coffee Do note, `-WhatIf`.  It won't actually delete the files, it'll just tell you what it does.

Comment: yeah did actually remove it, did run it like this



Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Files' -Filter 'App_*.zip' -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
                   $_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } |
    Sort-Object -Property 'LastWriteTime' -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Remove-Item -Force